# "Storage" in manifest.json for web extension has no effect

Tags: webextension-storage

I've added `"storage"` to my permissions array in the `manifest.json` file, but the browser console still reports `ReferenceError: storage is not defined` whenever I load it as a temporary extension in Firefox.

What else can I even do here??

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "browser.storage" or "chrome.storage" instead of "storage"

Had the same problem using

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage

as reference, which doesn't show you where the api is specified.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API